# XamDataGrid - adding columns at run time

Tags: c#, wpf, infragistics

I have a XamDataGrid and i provide a data source at run time. I want to hide some columns based on a user input field at run time. Here the same grid can be used by 3 different tables to display data.

Please give me some inputs to do this..

```
 private void EditAllocations_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ObservableCollection<LobAllocation> ds = _controller.PlanitariumModel.Entity.LobAllocations;

        if (editGridClickCheck((Button)sender, ds.Count))
        {
            EditGrid.DataSource = ds
        }
    }
```

The datasource has the following fields:

```
    AllocationKey, Description, Allocation, ParentAllocationPct, SubAllocation1, SubAllocation2, SubAllocation3, SubAllocation4, SubAllocation5, SubAllocation6, SubAllocation7, SubAllocation8, SubAllocation9
```

Now based on the user input, i want to select a combination of these fields which in turn should be allowed to be editable in the XamDataGrid.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to define all of the fields in your field layout that are possible and then set the Visibility of them based on what has been selected.  The example here may be of use to you:
http://www.infragistics.com/community/blogs/josh_smith/archive/2008/06/06/binding-a-xamdatagrid-field-property.aspx

There may be other options where you define the layout after you know what fields are needed as well.  What will work best isn't able to be determined from the details provided in the question.